# Execute jquery in newly opened window after click event

Tags: jquery, dom, onclick

I'm attempting to write jQuery to execute a click in a window that opens after the first click event.
In other words, I click a link on a page and it spawns a new window.  In that new window I'd like to execute another click.

These steps work manually.

```
1. $('a.button.btn')[0].click();  // on the first page
2. $('.dbtn a').trigger('click'); // on the page that loads
```

Unsuccessfully, I have attempted to capture the loaded page by doing things like,

```
var windowOpen = $('a.button.btn')[0].click();
$(windowOpen).$('.dbtn a').trigger('click');
```

or

```
var windowOpen = $('a.button.btn')[0].click();
windowOpen.addEventListener('load', function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $(windowOpen.document.body).find('.dbtn a').click();
    }, 2500);
}, false);
```

Ideally I will be looping over all buttons on the first page and executing the click again on the subsequent pages that load, but I'm not sure it's possible to perform this and then close out windows?

Thanks for any assistance!

Answer (score 0):

If you use javascript `click` on an `<a href="...">` it will not work, the browser prevents that. If you need to use javascript to make the behaviour of a user clicking a link, you have to read the `href` and then use `location.href` to make a redirect to that URL.

In my example I am getting all the `a` in the page, opening a pop up using the `href`, waiting for the popup to load, to get the `href` of the link inside the popup, and then call `location.href` in the pop up to make it redirect

See if this is what you need, just create both files in the same folder, and open index.html.

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <a href="windowToOpen.html?param=1">Open Window 1</a>

    <br /><br />

    <a href="windowToOpen.html?param=2">Open Window 2</a>

    <br /><br />

    <a href="windowToOpen.html?param=3">Open Window 3</a>

    <script>
      [...document.querySelectorAll("a")].forEach((a) => {
        const windowToOpen = window.open(a.href, "_blank", "width=500,height;500");

        const intervalId = setInterval(() => {
          if (windowToOpen.document.body.lastChild) {
            const linkInWindow = windowToOpen.document.querySelector(".dbtn a").href;
            windowToOpen.location.href = linkInWindow;
            clearInterval(intervalId);
          }
        }, 10);
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**windowToOpen.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="dbtn">
      <a href="https://stackoverflow.com">Stack Overflow</a>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```